# The capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet - how to prevent this error?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

in my application i am open Tshark process and start capturing, when i want to finish to capturing i am kill the Tshark process so sometimes the capture file is corrupted and when i am trying to open this file i received the error **the capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet - how to prevent this error**
there is a batter way to close the Tshark process to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 7):

Try stopping the capture process with ctrl+c instead of killing the process.

Also, you can try using [pcapfix](http://f00l.de/pcapfix/) to fix your corrupted packets, it may help making your existing files readable again.

Comment: i am open the process with windows = hidden so i don't see the windows, is it possible to stopping the capture process with ctrl+c ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is on UN*X, if you kill the process with `kill -INT`*pid*, then that will look just like a Ctrl+C.  I'm not sure there's an equivalent on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

I know this post is old, but in case anyone else runs across this:

The OP is probably running something like this:

```
tshark > capture.cap
```

And then killing it with CTRL+C. This will corrupt the file.

Instead of redirecting the output, use the -w option:

```
tshark -w capture.cap
```

Then you can kill it with CTRL+C and shouldn't have any corruption issues.

Comment: Running `tshark > capture.cap` won't even produce a capture file that's readable by Wireshark - it'll produce a *text* file with dissections of the packets.